# Crystal Reports has stopped working

Tags: crystal-reports

On only certain reports, Crystal Reports crashes and gives this error (see attached picture).

[image]

I am still relatively new to Crystal and am not sure how to diagnose this error or where to find error logs that might point me in the right direction.  I came across a post somewhere about windows version compatibility, but I'm not sure if that's it.

I'm running Crystal Reports product version 14.1.2.1121 on Windows 10.  Has anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: I have this problem too, but It happens with all my reports. My desktop application is made with WPF

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Crystal Reports in Windows 8.1, then later update your OS to Windows 10,then it will work fine :)

Comment: Our IT team doesn't want to go back to Windows 8.  Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is something that may happen from time to time in CR, except if you get this every time you open a report in particular or too often. Although the information need some additions. Is this on client or developer end?

Answer (score 0):

May you have to do following steps:
1. Right-click My Computer, then click Properties then click the Advanced tab.

2. Click the Performance Settings button then click the Data Execution Prevention tab.
3. Select the Turn on DEP for all programs and services except those I select: check box.
4. Add all of the Crystal Enterprise executables.
5. click ok. and close the window. open crystall report now.